# How to properly encrypt passwords in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, password-encryption

I'm trying to encrypt passwords in nodejs for a website using express.

Here is the function I use to encrypt the passwords:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

// the problem
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

encrypt(str) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    console.log(encrypted);
    return encrypted;
}
```

The problem with this code is that if I were to restart this the key would be different and I would be getting different strings for the same password that's saved in the database. This wouldn't work out because I won't be able to test the password with the hash when a user submits when trying to log in.

How can I make it so that I will always receive the same encrypted string and is there a more secure way to do everything, maybe even other libraries that would do the job better?

Comment: I just ended up using bcryptjs for this. Works perfectly!

Comment: You dont "encrypt" passwords. You hash them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally with nodejs bcryptjs is more suggested module for password encryption and decryption.

Follow below link to take an example of BcryptJs

[BcryptJs concept examples](https://medium.com/@vuongtran/using-node-js-bcrypt-module-to-hash-password-5343a2aa2342)

Comment: Ended up using bcryptjs!

Answer (score 0):

we can use crypto a native nodejs module, checkout the below sample code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
const hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync("<password>", salt, 
    1000, 64, `sha512`).toString(`hex`)
```

Further sample code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-password-hashing-crypto-module/

Note: all cryptic operations are CPU heavy try using the async function whenever possible.

Comment: when the program would restart the salt would be different and then you wouldn't be able to check it...

Comment: yes, I do agree, Still we can use a constant secret(config) instead of salt to hash the password.
The idea is to avoid extra packages and utilize native modules.

Answer (score -1):

Use Crypto-Js npm library.

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

const doc = await Users.create({
        password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
          req.body.password,
          process.env.PASS_SEC
        ).toString(),
      });
```

For comparing the password use below code.

```
const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        user.password,
        process.env.PASS_SEC
    );

const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
if (user.password == originalPassword)
return user;
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js